# Hexadecimal ReadOnlySpan<char> to Int as in Int32.Parse(chars.ToString(), HexSpecifier) (to avoid .ToString())?

Tags: c#

I already replaced .split/substring with `ReadOnlySpan<char>` approach to avoid allocation, because this function is going to run every 200ms, it does works, however, it would be perfect if I could avoid using `.ToString()`, so I could be free of DPA Analysis anxiety telling me that I had horrendous gigabyte of allocation.

So is there any way to convert hexadecimal `char[]` to `int`?

I had try this once, but I just don't know how to accumulate that hex value so `preParse` will contain 17092912 based from char iteration of `104D130`

```cs
int preParse = 0;
foreach (char c in chars)
{
    preParse += preparse + c;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

```cs
List<int> offsetsList = new List<int>();
int x = 0;
 foreach (ReadOnlySpan<char> chars in address.SplitWithSpan())
  {
   if (address.Contains("base") && x == 0)
    {
     x += 1;
     continue;
    }
    int preParse = 0;
    preParse = Int32.Parse(chars.ToString(),NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);                    offsetsList.Add(preParse);
    offsetsList.Add(preParse);
  }
```

this is why I wanted to not use .ToString()
[image]

Comment: Please show all code as *text* rather than as images, and don't randomly add headings. Note that a single call to `ToString` every 200ms is likely to get lost in the noise... but you should benchmark to check it.

Comment: Am I missing something?  If I was that worried about performance, I'd be more worried about the recurring calls to address.Contains("base") than the toString() call.  It doesn't appear address changes inside the loop, so why not check it before the loop?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, already did, also I added more picture from DPA analysis which showed allocated string, whereas traced back to this piece of code, that's after run for more than 10 hours

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for the insight, yes I'm worried about that as well, but DPA analysis shows nothing about it, also it was kind of quick workaround to skip first enumerator in the meantime, I shall refactor it

Comment: Please **do not** paste images of code or data, please paste them in as text

Answer (score 0):

assuming always upper case

```
int number = 0;
foreach (char c in chars)
{
    var value = char.IsDigit(c) ? c - '0' : c - 'A' + 10;
    number = (number << 4) + value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to get it done, further discussion are welcome to improve the code

[Geeksforgeeks: Program for Hexadecimal to Decimal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-hexadecimal-to-decimal/)
[image]

```cs
 int preParse = 0;
   // Iterate from right as in the picture above
   for (int i = chars.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     // add into accumulator
     // also power it from the right based on the digits (0,1,2,3..)
     // hex2int(chars[i])*16^0, 16^1, 16^2.. and so
     preParse += (int)(hex2int(chars[i]) * ( Math.Pow(16, (chars.Length-1)-i)));
   }
```

for hex2int, I found this in some thread but forgot the links.

```cs
int hex2int(char ch)
        {
            if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
                return ch - '0';
            if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
                return ch - 'A' + 10;
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
                return ch - 'a' + 10;
            return -1;
        }
```